# xcopy the whole folder in this case

Tags: batch-file

This is another problem that i got in the same code, that i have already asked for help, so i am not sure if it is a duplicate or not.

The problem now is when i run the script, at the command xcopy i wanted to be able to copy the whole folder that the file is located instead of only the file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p COU1=COU No. 1 serial number?:
echo COU serial number is: %COU1%
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d AssayInfo.txt') do (
  for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('type "%%~fi" ^| findstr /i "CouID"') do set "number=%%a"
    echo Found number !number! in file "%%~fi"
    if !number!==!COU1! xcopy "%%~fi" "C:\dev\WORKING"
pause
)
```

so to simplify i want to copy the whole folder that the file "~fi" was found instead of only the file

i also tried something like this:

```
set /p COU1=COU No. 1 serial number?:
echo COU serial number is: %COU1%
for /D %%k in ("C:\dev\*") do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%i in ('type "%%k\AssayInfo.txt" ^| findstr /i CouID') do set "number=%%j" 
if %number%==%COU1% (echo Hello it worked) else (echo ERROR:No files with that serial number)
pause
```

but the problem here it is the IF statment its outside the FOR, so it will keep changing the !number! even if it matches, and will take the last value found not the one that is equal to COU1.

Comment: `xcopy /E "%%~fi" "C:\dev\WORKING"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard thanks for aways answering me, but it still only copying the txt file, and nit the whole folder. i need to copy the folder that the file is in.

Comment: Please show me that the value of `%%~fi` looks like

Comment: its a txt file, inside a folder. C:\dev\138527012\AssayInfo.txt. i need to copy the whole C:\dev\138527012\

Comment: ok, so you want to copy `138527012` into `WORKING`? so it will look like: `C:\dev\WORKING\138527012`?

Comment: oh and does it have the \ at end of each entry? 138527012\

Comment: yes, but the the 138527012 is a folder holding the AssayInfo.txt, so it can changes depending where the AssayInfo has been found. just to clarify i will have some folder with different names containing the AssayInfo.txt file, and each AssayInfo.txt will have a different CouID number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use robocopy here. But you were trying to copy the filename, not the folder, remember we set `!number!` as the found value.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p COU1=COU No. 1 serial number?:
echo COU serial number is: %COU1%
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d AssayInfo.txt') do (
  for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('type "%%~fi" ^| findstr /i "CouID"') do set "number=%%a"
    echo Found number !number! in file "%%~fi"
    set "fpat=%%~dpi"
    set "fpat=!fpat:~0,-1!"
    for %%u in (!fpat!) do set "dst=%%~nu"
    if "!number!"=="!COU1!" robocopy "!fpat!" "C:\dev\WORKING\!dst!" /E
    pause
)
```

Comment: it worked like a charm, the only thing i gave you a bad exemple, because the folder will not aways have the same name as the !number!. the AssayInfo.txt has that Number, so i need to use the user input to find the folder that holds the AssayInfo.txt that holds the same number.

Comment: but the `!number!` is what we get from the file?

Comment: yes, !number! is what we find in the file and COU1 is a user input(scan)

Comment: So then I do not see the problem? User inputs a number `1234` we match it with `!number!` and if it matches i.e `1234` = `1234` we copy the dir. Is that not it?

Comment: yes, but the folder that holds the file AssayInfo.txt(the file that holds the number) sometimes will not have the same name as !number!. for exemple: i have a folder named 1597 that holds a AssauInfo.txt (with !number! = 138527011)

Comment: ah.. so you want to copy from the number where the file existed.. ok, I see now.

Comment: @joao try now please.

Comment: man, it worked! thank you very much for all the help! You are a very helpful and humble people!

Comment: btw.. is it possible to copy the folder and also make it have the same name it had before?

Comment: it is supposed to do that already, what is the new name then?

Comment: hellooo its the new name

Comment: LOL, sorry, that was a generic pathname... let me fix it.

Comment: fixed, try now please.

Comment: Thank you! batch wizard

Answer (score 1):

Had you provided all of the information you needed at the outset, you wouldn't have needed `4` questions to achieve this task.

Based upon what we now know, I would have suggested you perform the task like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "COU1="

:Ask
Set /P "COU1=COU No. 1 serial number?: "
If Not Defined COU1 GoTo Ask

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /SMIC:"CouId: %COU1%" "AssayInfo.txt" 2^>Nul^
 ^|FindStr /VBLI "WORKING\\"') Do @For %%B In ("%%~dpA."
) Do XCopy "%%~B" "C:\dev\WORKING\%%~nxB" /ECIHRKY>Nul 2>&1
```

*Based on the info you provided this script would be ran from `C:\dev`.*

Comment: joao, the example above deliberately ignores anything already inside the `C:\dev\WORKING` when searching the content of the files, and should be significantly more efficient than the answer you've already accepted too!